# how can I automatically check notifications on codeigniter / jquery ratchet?

Tags: php, codeigniter, websocket, ratchet

I want to check my notifications on my app , I would like to send from my own system notifications to the user not added them, but how can I detect them automatically?

```
public function pusher(){
         $entryData = array(
             'category' => $this->input->post('category'), 
             'title'    => $this->input->post('title'), 
             'article'  => $this->input->post('article'), 
             'when'     => time()
         );

        //$this->notification->addNotification($entryData);

        // This is our new stuff

        $context = new ZMQContext();
        $socket = $context->getSocket(ZMQ::SOCKET_PUSH, 'my pusher');
        $socket->connect("tcp://localhost:5555");

        $socket->send(json_encode($entryData));
        print_r($entryData);

    }
```

model notifications

```
public function checkForNotifications($user_id, $lastAjaxCall){
        $sql = "SELECT COUNT(*) as notificationCount FROM storelte_user_notifications WHERE timestamp > ?  AND user_id = ?";
        $result = $this->db->query($sql, array($user_id, $lastAjaxCall))->result_array();
        print_r($result[0]['notificationCount']);
        return $result[0]['notificationCount'];
    }

    public function getNotifications($user_id, $lastAjaxCall){
        $sql =  "SELECT * FROM storelte_user_notifications LEFT JOIN storelte_notifications on storelte_user_notifications.notification_id = storelte_notifications.id WHERE timestamp > ? AND user_id = ? ORDER by timestamp";
        $result = $this->db->query($sql, array($user_id, $lastAjaxCall))->result_array();
        return $result;
    }
```

websocket jquery.

```
$('#btn-simpan').click(function() {
        $.ajax({
            url: URL_GET_NOTIFICATION,
            type: 'POST',
            data: { category: $('#category').val(), title: $('#title').val(),  article: $('#article').val() }
        }).done(function(data) {
            console.log(data);
        });
    });

    var conn = new ab.Session('ws://192.168.0.4:8080',
        function() {
            conn.subscribe('kittensCategory', function(topic, data) {
                $badge.show();
                $badge.text(parseInt($badge.text()) + 1);

                $list.find(".item").eq(13).nextAll(".item").remove();
                var item = '<li class="item text-warning"><a href="#"><span class="text-warning">' +
                    '<i class="fa fa-exclamation-triangle fa-fw"></i>'+data.title+' is low'+'</span>' +
                    '<span class="pull-right text-muted small" data-time="">X</span></a></li>' +
                    '<li class="item divider"></li>';
                $list.prepend(item);
                $('.dropdown.open .dropdown-toggle').dropdown('toggle');
            });
        },
        function() {
            console.warn('WebSocket connection closed');
        }, {
            'skipSubprotocolCheck': true
        }
    );
```